# Almost principal ideals

Tags: ring-theory, terminology, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a non-unital ring. Then given an $r\in R$, we may have $r\notin Rr$, so $Rr$ is not necessarily the left ideal generated by $r$.

It is not hard to see that $Rr$ may not even be a principal ideal (for example, if $R$ is the maximal ideal of a densely valued ring), even though it is always a (left) ideal.

Is there a name for these sorts of ideals?